# How can we change placeholder of state dropdown field on checkout page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, translate

How can we change placeholder of state Dropdown field on checkout page in Magento2

Comment: use translation csv for that

Comment: alright any other method for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Please override it OR make a plugin.

Here is the path where you can make a change.

> /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/ResourceModel/Region/Collection.php

line number 258

```
    if (count($options) > 0) {
            array_unshift(
                $options,
                ['title' => '', 'value' => '', 'label' => __('Please select a region, state or province.')]
            );
        }
```

note: answer is based on magento 2.2.6

Comment: can you please share a code for afterExecute plugin for this. because the $result return me nothing

Comment: please add your code in question I will try to figure it out

Comment: `public function afterToOptionArray($subject, $result){
        $this->_localeResolver->getLocale();
        //$result['0']['lable'] = 'Hello';
        $resultFirst = $result['0'];
        $labelClass = $resultFirst['label'];

         $currentLabel = $labelClass->getText();`

Comment: I did this above but its not allowing me to setText() , I'm just able to getText()

Comment: For set use before plugin instead of after